# How to Display CalculaterPanel by Double Clicking on GWT NumberCell

Tags: gwt

I want to display calculator panel by double clicking the GWT NumberCell as like DatePicker cell,

how to achieve this,

Answer (score 0):

External plugins can be used to achieve complex functionality.

Please refer to the following link : [jQuery Calculator](http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html)

Use JSNI Functions to interact with plain java script / jQuery. Follow the link to have better insight about JSNI : [Writing JSNI methods in GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)

Comment: I couldnt understand how to render it in my code, can you provide me any source code ?

Comment: This link ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/rXI0h9lYg7Y ) displays how to add a datepicker to UI using JSNI. similar concept can be used to add the Calculator.